# Typing speed for updating results

Tags: user-behavior, autocomplete, typing

I'm implementing some ajax autocomplete. Whenever user types something result gets displayed.
One thing that is bad about those autocomplete is that constantly hitting database.

So I went with making some timeout to decide if user stopped typing.

So here is the question, what would you suggested for timeout? Currently I have half of the second.

Comment: I'm confused when you say "always hitting the database." There are multiple ways to look for user interactions without a timer. Is there something in your situation that demands a timer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest another approach.  Instead of hitting the database every single keystroke or after a particular interval, why not hit the database one time on page load, pull down your dataset of possibilities, and filter off of that?  Doing that would be nearly instantaneous.

---

It's a few years old, but this article may be of interest to you as well:

## [Building Fast Client-side Searches](http://code.flickr.net/2009/03/18/building-fast-client-side-searches/)

Here is a small excerpt:

> There was one optimization we made to our AutoComplete configuration
> that was particularly effective. Regardless of how much we optimized
> our search method, we could never get results to return in less than
> 200ms (even for trivially small numbers of contacts). After a lot of
> profiling and hair pulling, we found the queryDelay setting. This is
> set to 200ms by default, and artificially delays every search in order
> to reduce UI flicker for quick typists. After setting that to 0, we
> found our search times improved dramatically.

Comment: this is interesting, since my markup would allow this but not sure about memory since I can have about million such things that should be filtered. (current problem) but still will not accept as anwer since I still interested in others opinions. I have different places when using such approach such as searching youtube videos.

Comment: @Mpa4Hu - A million things may sound like a lot, but the only way to know for sure is to simply test it.

Comment: A million things may sound like a lot, but it is a lot! With average word length in English being 5.1 chars a million words would roughly be 4.86MB. Fetching that much extra for a page load is unjustified. Take into account how many people might be on a [slow connection](http://www.fastcompany.com/3016298/3-of-americans-still-use-dial-up-internet) or using mobile devices with limited data plans.